# LazyInitializationException in AOP logger aspect

Tags: spring, jsf, jpa

I have an app build with Spring, JSF JPA and Hibernate.
I have an aspect that "watches" every update*, create*,delete* method from my service layer of the application. This aspect logs the method params, apply toString to every param and them log them in the database. The problem is that I use domain objects in jsf and when i try to update* something i get a LazyInitializationException when toString() is applied to the method param.
One solution would be to remove from toString all params that represents other objects but then the operation has no sense as i do not log the details that interests me.
ie. I have an entity called Price which has a dependency PriceList:

```
public class Price extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to TelCoPriceList
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "price_list_id")
    private PriceList priceList;
.....................
}
```

And the price is used into AddPriceForm.xhtml, which is the jsf form. The JSF AddPriceMB has a reference to PriceService which performs the actual update.
The PriceService is "monitored" by this aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Named("auditLogAspectImpl")
public class AuditLogAspectImpl implements AuditLogAspect {

@Inject
private UserService userService; 

@Inject
private AuditLogService auditLogService;

@Override
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.videanuadrian.core.impl.services..*.save*(..)) or execution(* com.videanuadrian.core.impl.services..*.update*(..)) or execution(* com.videanuadrian.core.impl.services..*.delete*(..))", returning = "retVal")
public boolean afterLogEvent(JoinPoint joinPoint,Object retVal) {

    String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName();
    String methondName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();

...................................................................      
    StringBuffer logMessage = new StringBuffer();       
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();    

    //for login action we only get the username and hash the password
    if (methondName.compareTo("login") == 0){           
        logMessage.append(args[0]);         
    }else {

        int argsLen = args.length;
        //else log all the parameters
        for (int i = 0; i < argsLen; i++) {
            // this is where the exception occurs !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            logMessage.append(args[i]).append(",");
        }

        if (argsLen > 0) {
            logMessage.deleteCharAt(logMessage.length() - 1);
        }
    }

    //some save/update methods return Boolean
        Boolean status = false;
        if (retVal instanceof Boolean){
            status = (Boolean) retVal;
        }

        //some return the ID of the object inserted,and if these methods return an integer the status is true, if they return null, the status si false
        if (retVal instanceof Integer){
            if (retVal!=null)
                status = true;  
        }

    auditLogService.addAuditLogEvent(uid, className+"."+methondName, status,logMessage.toString());     
    return true;
}
```

On a prior version I did not had this problem because I had used DTO objects and the conversion between DTO and Domain Objects was performed in the service layer. The error is very clear, as my session was closed long ago compared to the time that I perform this toString() operation.
Any idea how can i achieve this without using openSessionInView or extended persistence context? Or maybe my approach is not good....

Comment: Don't use AOP but rather implement Hibernate Event Listeners for this kind of task. Check also Hibernate Envers project.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hints. I have used envers before but i was looking for a generic solution.

Comment: I understand. If you really want to go the AOP way, then you might also consider not using entities as service method arguments. You can implement special transfer objects instead (e.g. for `Price` entity implement `PriceUpdate` object). Then you won't have problems with lazy initialization. The downside is that the number of objects in the application (and required mapping logic between those objects) increases quite a lot.

Comment: :) A month ago I had such setup where every DomainObject was backed up by a DTO object with the exact same fields, and in views i have used that DTO`s. Thanks for the hints.